# How to omit/prevent data from being sent to the POST method in the Controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a view that is using a model and I am using that information to create a form.
I have three steps of the form that are optional or may not be shown.

The problem is that these hidden sections get posted along with the form data and break the business logic. (I have no control over the business logic)

**So is there a way to tell the framework not to pass certain sections or fields? Perhaps VIA a class or something?**

*I know I could use AJAX to send certain sections as they are needed, but the site spec is to have them hidden and displayed as needed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show/Hide will not allow/disallow the value from being sent to the `Controller`.

Elements that are **`Disabled`** or just not editable will (99% of the time) be **returned as `null` / `minVal`**.

You can set the elements in the View as `Disabled` by using `JQuery` in the script:

```
$('#elementID').attr("disabled", true);
```

OR you could use a `DOM` command:

```
document.getElementById('elementID').disabled = "true";
```

So you can **set the fields as both `Disabled` AND `Hidden`**, so that it is **neither displayed, nor populated**. Then in your `Controller` you can just base the Business Logic on whether or not certain fields (preferable Mandatory fields, if you have any) are null.

---

You can check this in `C#` like this:
For a **`string`**:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.stringField))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("stringField", "This is an error.");
}
```

For a **`DateTime`**:

```
if (Model.dateTimeField == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("dateTimeField ", "This is an error.");
}
```

---

Just for interest sake, here is how you can Hide/Show elements on the View using `JQuery`:

```
$('#elementID').hide();
$('#elementID').show();
```

Comment: OK, so there's no way to just say "Don't post this entire section"? Aside from having to set each individual item to disabled?

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, the Model that is expected as parameter in the POST method will be received wholly as it is predetermined. However, whether or not each field contains data is not predetermined.

Answer (score 2):

Although you could do this client-side, it won't stop malicious [over-posting/mass assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability).

I suggest reading [6 Ways To Avoid Mass Assignment in ASP.NET MVC](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/12/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Excerpts:

Specify Included Properties only:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit([Bind(Include = "FirstName")] User user)
{
  // ...
}
```

Specify Excluded Properties only:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "IsAdmin")] User user)
{
  // ...
}
```

Use `TryUpdateModel()`

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit()
{
  var user = new User();
  TryUpdateModel(user, includeProperties: new[] { "FirstName" });
  // ...
}
```

Using an Interface

```
public interface IUserInputModel
{
  string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class User : IUserInputModel
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit()
{
  var user = new User();
  TryUpdateModel<IUserInputModel>(user);
  // ...
}
```

Use the `ReadOnlyAttribute`

```
public class User 
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  [ReadOnly(true)]
  public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly, and the most recommended approach is to use a real ViewModel, instead a domain Model:

```
public class UserInputViewModel
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```